# Is there a more elegant way to execute this switch statement?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a large switch statement in my code, and I want it to do something like this:

```
// assign $foo
switch ($foo) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        // do X, then break if 1, do Y and break if 2
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
       // do A & B, break if 3, do C if 4 or 5, do D if 5 and then break
}
```

Such "groups" are prevalent throughout the switch statement and currently I just repeat the logic, keeping each case separate.
Am I wrong in assuming that this could be restructured into something that's objectively "better"?

**Edit:** I excluded my original code snippet from the question, since it had deeply flawed logic and didn't conform to the basic concepts of using a `switch`, replacing it with pseudocode that resembles the desired result.

Comment: Ivan Talanov: I think this is the only way to use the switch statements. There are alternatives to this but those are not suggestible with switch as it causes towards high cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: I don't know how that supposedly "works": https://3v4l.org/t06Eg. A `switch` isn't multi-entry; the first matching `case` starts execution of *all* following statements regardless of what other `case` they may be nested in, and the first `break` that is encountered completely exists the `switch`. The second `case 1` will *always* be executed and the second `case 2` will *never* be executed.

Comment: @deceze You seem to be right, I had an error in the "real" logic, which made me believe this thing was working correctly and led to the wrong MCVP - but the question's main point whether I could do something like "for 1 & 2, do X, then if 1 break, if 2, do Y and then break" using a switch is stil relevant.

Comment: Simply `if ($foo == 1 || $foo == 2) { ... if ($foo == 2) { ... } }`? Of `if ($foo == 2)` inside the `switch..case 1: case 2:`?

Comment: @deceze the if inside the switch now seems obvious to me and I'm puzzled how I didn't think of that myself - thanks! You could post it as an answer if you'd like, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, that `switch` doesn't actually work as you think.

You're simply looking for:

```
if (in_array($foo, [1, 2])) {
    ...

    if ($foo == 2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        ...

        if ($foo == 2) {
            ...
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting as well, the OP has 2x `case 1:` in the code, making me believe they are thinking that switches for for `case AND case` when using fall through, where they use `case or case` and the second `case 1:` won't be accessed as the first will be used and then broken out of

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**;
For simple "is it this", use a switch, if you need logical checks, use an if

**The answer;**
What you are asking is quite subjective, while using a switch for something simple is good, i.e;

```
<?php
$case = getCaseFrom("X"); // Let's say this = "a"

switch ($case)
{
    case "a" : {
        $thing = "a";
        break;
    }
    case "b" : {
        $thing = "b";
        break;
    }
    case "c" : {
        $thing = "c";
        break;
    }
    default : {
        $thing = "d";
    }
}
?>
```

The same could be achieved by using;

```
<?php
$case = getCaseFrom("x");
$thing = $case;
// And even shorter;
$thing = getCaseFrom("x");
?>
```

Whereas, if you needed some logic to this...

```
<?php
$operator = getOperatorFrom("X"); // In this case, add
$num1 = 10;
$num2 = 2;

switch ($operator)
{
    case "add" : {
        $res = num1 + num2;
        break;
    }
    case "subtract" : {
        $res = num1 - num2;
        break;
    }
    case "multiply" : {
        $res = num1 * num2;
        break;
    }
    case "divide" : {
        $res = num1 / num2;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

**The alternative;**
And of course, all of the above switches case be done using `if else` clauses, but a switch (IMO) is a neater, and more readable approach depending on what your certain criteria are (see the drawbacks).

The easiest way to look at it is;

> If you need to check if something matches a value, use an if, if it is an enumerated set of values (let's say 1 to 4), a switch is subjectively better

**The drawbacks;**
A switch also doesn't let you have multiple "and" checks in the same statement, for example;

```
<?php

$case = getCaseFrom("X"); // In this case, a (does not have "b")
switch ($case)
{
    case "a" :
    case "b" : {
        // This checks for a or b, not both, despite this not containing "b"
        // this will still be accessed
        break;
    }
    case "c" : {
        // This will not be used as the break stops
        // it from falling through to this clause
        break;
    }
}

if (stristr("a", $case) && stristr("b", $case)) 
{
    // This checks to see if case contains a AND b
    // therefore, this will not be used, as this 
    // does not have both a and b in $case
}
else if (stristr("a", $case) || stristr("b", $case)) 
{
    // This checks to see if case contains a OR b
    // therefore, this will be used, as this 
    // is checking that $case has "a" or "b" in it
    // This is the same as the switch in this instance as it uses "or"
}
```

**The noteworthy;**
To be aware of the following also would be useful;

Inside a switches `case`, you cannot use login, for example;

```
case getThing("a") :
```

would cause an error

**NB**: Of course, when using the `case` statements, you don't need the curly braces added, they are mainly for code folding and ease of reading